# Reuse Scala type as bounds in method definition

Tags: scala, generics, types, existential-type, type-bounds

Is it possible to write something like this and reuse the HelperTest.AnyHelper type?

```
class HelperUtil 
{    
/* this is what I would like to write... reuse the AnyHelper type in the definition */
   def accept[HelperTest.AnyHelper](helper : HelperTest.AnyHelper) = 
   {
       // code here
   }
}

object HelperTest 
{
    type AnyHelper = T forSome { type T <: GenericHelper }
}

abstract class GenericHelper 
{
    val name = ""
}
```

Currently I am forced to write this, since the compiler won't let me:

```
class HelperUtil 
{
/* gets too verbose, if the generic type gets more complex and would be useful to reuse the type */
    def accept[T <: GenericHelper](helper : T) = 
    {
        // code here
    }
}

abstract class GenericHelper 
{
    val name = ""
}
```

Or am I completely on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are mistaken about how type parameters in a signature such as `def accept[T]` work. The type variable `T` in this signature gets *bound*, that is, `T` is introduced as a new type variable. If there already exists a type variable with the same name in the current context, then it will be shadowed by the newly bound `T`. Consider this example:

```
class Foo[T] {
  def id[T](t: T) = t
}
```

The class signature binds a new `T` that can be referred to in the class body. However, the method signature binds a `T` as well, which shadows the class `T`. With the result, that you can instantiate the class `T` with some type `X` and the method `T` with some other type `Y`:

```
val f = new Foo[String]
f.id(0)
```

Back to your code. Your signature

```
def accept[HelperTest.AnyHelper](helper : HelperTest.AnyHelper)
```

thus tries to bind a new type variable `HelperTest.AnyHelper` - which the compiler rejects, because type variables may not contain a dot (`.`).

Do the following instead:

```
import scala.language.existentials

trait A
class B1 extends A
class C1 extends B1
class B2 extends A

object HelperUtil {
  type MyA = T forSome { type T <: A }
}

class HelperUtil {
   /* Reuse type declaration */
   def foo(a: HelperUtil.MyA) = println(a.getClass.getName)
   def bar(a: HelperUtil.MyA) = println(a.getClass.getName)
   def baz(a: HelperUtil.MyA) = println(a.getClass.getName)
}

val hu = new HelperUtil

/* Instantiate with different types */
hu.foo(new B1) // B1
hu.foo(new B2) // B2
hu.bar(new C1) // C1
```

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to "reuse" the type generic parameter, because that exact parameter is used several places. Is there way, or some other implementation suggestion?

Comment: @slaursen I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean with "reuse". You already reuse the type `HelperTest.AnyHelper` by declaring `helper` to be of that type.

Comment: Example where "[A <: Something[A]]" is repeated over and over. If the bound was even more complex it would be hell and error prone to keep repeating it. 

`object SomeObject 
{
    def method1[A <: Something[A]](parm : A) = {...}
    def method2[A <: Something[A]](text : String,parm : A) = {...}
    def method3[A <: Something[A]](parm : A) : List[A] = {...}
    etc
}`